# Cross platform Social Media Sharing only on Facebook,twitter and Instagram using Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I want to share the text and URL on Facebook,twitter,instagram using Xamarin cross platform functionality. I have used plugin.share but it is showing all other options as well. I just need to show the user - Facebook,instagram and twitter as options in the share sheet.

Comment: This plugin will open the system popup share view when you want to share a file . And it will include sharing with, Facebook, Email, SMS or any other app that has registered support for the file type.For example PDF readers can handle a PDF, or Facebook and other apps would be able to share image files. So you could not block some app which you don't want to display .

Comment: Can you please suggest something else to share on these three platforms only

Comment: I don't think you can implement it . The possible way is define a custom popup view and implement the logic of share by yourself , which will be very complex .

Comment: @LucasZhang u never shared a plugin !